# Ruby on Rails Flash Now Multiple Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, error-handling

I'm fairly new to ROR so I need a little help in getting form validation errors to display correctly. I have a form that gets submitted with Ajax so for errors I'm using `flash.now`. I want the errors to display in a list. I tried different things but either it will display the whole unformatted hash, the last item or all of them as one list item.I followed the documentation and the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878662/how-to-display-ruby-on-rails-form-validation-error-messages-one-at-a-time), but I can't get it to work mainly because I'm trying to display multiple errors in a list format. I'm not sure if the problem is how I'm binding the error object into the flash or how I have the partial setup to display the flash.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanx

I've tried these variations:

```
flash.now[:alert] = @message.errors.full_messages

flash.now[:alert] = @message.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
```

Flash Partial

```
.flash-wrapper
    - flash.each do |key, value| 
        div class="alert alert-#{key}"
            span.close
            ul.disc
                li
                    = value
```

Comment: Did you try  '  li = value  '  in your Flash Partial?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't do anything. value still has all of the errors combined. I think I have to call another each function to get the values from the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- flash[:alert].each do |value|
```

I guess

```
- flash.each do |key, value|
```

gives 'alert' as the key, and the array of error messages as the value.

So check the value of #{key} in

```
div class="alert alert-#{key}"
```