# In a included partial how do you render the original page with validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form, erb

I have a page with a partial containing a form in my rails app (5.1.1)

I am using the simple_form gem.

This page is for showing details of a  a Journey, which can contain many legs. Inside the journey view, we render a partial `"_form"` for the legs view. This view contains a form which creates a new leg to add to the journey, and in this case is being rendered from the `'show'` view of journey.

## journeys/show.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">
 <h3><%= @journey.name %></h3>
 <h4><%= @journey.legs.count %> <%= "leg".pluralize(@journey.legs.count) %> covering <%= @journey.total_distance.round(1) %> <%="mile".pluralize(@journey.total_distance)%>!</h4>

 <hr/>
 <h4><%= (@journey.has_legs) ? 'Add another leg to the journey' : "Your journey has no legs, and we all know a journey can't go far without its legs! Quick...give it some legs..." %></h4>

    <%= render partial: "legs/form", locals: {leg: @new_legs.first} %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_journey_path(@journey) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', journeys_path %>
</div>
```

When a validation error occurs on the leg that is being created, due to the leg's create action code - it renders the :new view of the leg, which works and shows all errors etc on the new view for the leg. This is due to the following action code on the legs controller:

## create action of legs

```
def create
    @leg = Leg.new(leg_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @leg.save
        format.html { redirect_to @leg, notice: 'leg was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @leg }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @leg.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

However, I would like to render the journey's "show" view showing all errors as would be seen on the :new view of the leg.

I know you can do `render "journeys/show"` which renders the show view of the journey, however, it doesn't persist the validation errors in the rendered partial `"legs/form"`.

How do I render the journey show view, making sure to pass it all validation errors on the included partial? I have tried using `redirect_back(fallback_path=>root_url)`but that does not persist the errors.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was relatively simple - thanks to the freenode #rubyonrails channel for helping.

Pass the partial a controller created instance of @leg, this @leg object will either be a new object, or it will be the old object with all errors in it.

Create that @leg in the journeys show controller, and in the leg create action, if it fails, create a @journey instance variable from @leg.journey and then render "journeys/show" et voila, everything works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

Upd: it is not the best advise, but it can set you to right direction. i think it sounds as [How to display Ruby on Rails form validation error messages one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878662/how-to-display-ruby-on-rails-form-validation-error-messages-one-at-a-time)
also here it describes http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#errorsadd
in my case i use this feature without db validation:
controller:

```
def create
      ...
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid data'
      render 'index'
end
```

view `index.html.erb`

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I see what you are doing there, but thats far more manual a solution as I was hoping for. I would prefer for Rails to take control of the lifting of this - I shouldn't need to manually pull out all validation errors, and then manually loop through and show them all on associated fields in the form. That is the reason I use rails / simple_form - to take that lifting away from me. Thanks for your suggestion, it would work - but not what I am looking for.

Comment: if serious saying, I tried to help and I really supposed that it would be useful for you.