# Rails 5 Simple Form does not display errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

The only way I can get my Simple form to display an error is via

```
  <% errors = f.object.errors.messages.collect { |k,v| "#{k}: #{v}" if v.length > 0 }.join("\n")%>
  <%= f.error_notification message: "Errors: #{errors}" %>
```

Which seems way too complicated.

**Scenario:**

User table and nested, polymorphic table of social_profile links (facebook, twitter, etc).

If the user does not fill out any of the nested form when creating a new account, the profile inputs/params are empty strings and it saves fine.

However, if the user deletes all the profile links' input fields then the association to the social_profile table will not be created. Thus, if the user later tries to edit his account the nested social_profile form will not be displayed.

Adding `validates :social_profile, presence: true, associated: true` to the User's model prevents this error from happening, but there is no indication of what occurred given to the user. The best I could come up with is the original code, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Brad Werth linked me to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878662/how-to-display-ruby-on-rails-form-validation-error-messages-one-at-a-time) which helped me construct the following answer:

```
<%= f.object.errors.full_messages.join(", ") if f.object.errors.any? %>
```

Grabs the error'ed object from the form, gets the "full_messages" (ie "Description cannot be blank") and joins them together with commas.